# cyclicapp ERR deploy laravel9+inertiajs

Tags: deployment

hye,

since yesterday I try to deploy my application on cyclicapp but it gives me this error:

Could not resolve '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m' from resources/js/app.js
error during build:

package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "start": "npm start"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.11.0",
        "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3": "^0.6.0",
        "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.7",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.2",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
        "axios": "^0.27",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.6.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.4.14",
        "sass": "^1.55.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.0",
        "vite": "^3.0.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.31"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.1.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.36",
        "vue-loader": "^17.0.0"
    }
}
```

vite.config.js :

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: "resources/js/app.js",
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

app.js:

```
import "./bootstrap";
import "../css/app.css";

import { createApp, h } from "vue";
import { createInertiaApp } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
import { InertiaProgress } from "@inertiajs/progress";
import { resolvePageComponent } from "laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers";
import { ZiggyVue } from "../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m";

const appName =
    window.document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]?.innerText || "Laravel";

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) =>
        resolvePageComponent(
            `./Pages/${name}.vue`,
            import.meta.glob("./Pages/**/*.vue")
        ),
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .mount(el);
    },
});

InertiaProgress.init({ color: "#4B5563" });
```

myproject is a laravel9 + inertia js + vue3 + jetstream
any help please

Comment: could you resolve the issue? If yes, please post the solution for others to see.

Comment: no solution right now im in heroku

Answer (score 0):

When I've had this issue it's been because composer hadn't been run.

Usually, this occurs during deployment, where I'm attempting to run `npm run build` in a deployment environment on which I don't install composer dependencies on.

For my issue, I copy the required `ziggy.vue.m.js` file to my codebase and commit, not ideal but it solves the issue.